# Docker Wordpress Returning 500 Server Error

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, apache2

I was using the wordpress docker container for development when I started geting this error in my browser:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.57 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 8080
```

And this error in my terminal:

```
wordpress-1  | [Wed Feb 21 19:18:21.258309 2024] [core:alert] [pid 38] [client 192.168.65.1:37509] /var/www/html/.htaccess: </IfModule> without matching <IfModule> section
wordpress-1  | 192.168.65.1 - - [21/Feb/2024:19:18:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 801 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

I tried restarting the container, but that didn't work. Then I fully stopped the container, and started it again. That didn't work either. I started doing some research and found out it was an apache2 server issue. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may encounter this problem, this is the fix:

The error is occurring in your `.htaccess` file.

This is the error message  `</IfModule> without matching <IfModule>`.

Log into the WordPress container and open the `.htaccess` file. Then add an opening `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` to match the closing `</IfModule>` tag missing an opening tag. Or remove the entire block if it's unnecessary, (You might not want to do this in production).